# font size of \footcite of biblatex in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, citing, fontsize

I have unsuccessfully tried to control the font size of `\footcite` with `\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\tiny}`? Is there any other way?

Comment: ok, it looks like `\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}` does the job.

Comment: You can use `citesetup`. This command stands before every cite-command.

Comment: @pluton If either does the job for you you should add it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @pluton: In relation to my answer I would change the title "How can I set the font size of `\footcite` separably in `biblatex`"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changing the fontsize with `\citesetup` will affect all citations, not only those in footnotes. Simply redefining `\footnotesize` to `\scriptsize` wouldn't be advisable for `article` or `book` documents because the standard `\footnotesize` command includes settings for the vertical spacing of lists and displayed equations, while `\scriptsize` doesn't. This, on the other hand, shouldn't be of concern in a `beamer` document. So I'd say that

```
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
```

is the way to go.

EDIT: I had forgotten about the `biblatex` conditional `\iffootnote`. I still think that redefining `\footnotesize` is preferable because it will also affect non-citation footnotes.

Comment: Why do you think it is preferable to redefine `\footnotesize`. The OP wants to control the font size of `\footcite`

Comment: From the OP's first comment, I infer that is acceptable to change the font size of every footnote, `\footcite` or not. This also helps to keep the document layout consistent. BTW, I upvoted your answer. :-)

Comment: The up/downvote isn't the problem. I think to combine our knowledge has the first priority. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `\iffootnote` in combination with `\AtEveryCitekey`.

Here the example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author="John Smith",
  title="The title",
  year=1099,
  publisher="nobody",  
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffootnote{\color{red}\scriptsize}{\color{blue}}}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Text on the frame\footcite{test}\quad\cite{test}

\textbf{\bibname}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The command `\citesetup` is used in front of the cite-command. In such cases you can use:

```
\appto\citesetup{\Huge}
```

The test `\iffootnote` failse because `citesetup` is used before `foot..` works. You can only test things like: `\footnote{Bla \cite{..}}`.

[image]

Comment: +1 But there have been [ongoing issues with `\iffootnote`](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3187507&group_id=244752&atid=1126005) and packages that redefine `\footnote`, such as `beamer` and `memoir`. I'm not sure if they have been entirely resolved in the latest `biblatex` release.

Comment: @Audrey: I didn't test it. When I'm home I will do it.

Comment: @Audrey: The example works but I also get the warning `Patching footnotes failed` ;-)

Comment: I understood that warning to generally imply that there will be problems with footnote detection. Perhaps it's more like "might be" instead of "will be".

Comment: @Audrey: Nice interpretation.